# Firebase iOS Swift: Cannot store object of type FIRTimestamp at

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, timestamp

I have an item object that I'd like to store on firebase, but the date timestamp isn't letting that happen.

Here is my Item struct:

```
    struct Item{
    var id: String = ""
    var itemName: String = ""
    var imageUrl: String = ""
    var price: String = ""
    var description = ""
    var categoryId = ""
    var postedBy = ""
    var postedByName = ""
    var coordinate = ""
    var date = Timestamp()


    func toDictionary() -> [String: Any]{
        return [ItemFields.ID: id,
                ItemFields.ITEM_NAME: itemName,
                ItemFields.IMAGE_URL: imageUrl,
                ItemFields.PRICE: price,
                ItemFields.DESCRIPTION: description,
                ItemFields.CATEGORY_ID: categoryId,
                ItemFields.POSTED_BY: postedBy,
                ItemFields.POSTED_BY_NAME: postedByName,
                ItemFields.COORDINATE: coordinate, 
                ItemFields.DATE: date
        ]
    }
}
```

When saving the item

```
 ref.setValue(item.toDictionary, withCompletionBlock: {(err, ref) in
```

I get this error:

> Cannot store object of type FIRTimestamp at date. Can only store
>   objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase offers two databases, Realtime Database and Firestore.  You didn't say which database you're writing to, but the fact that you're calling `setValue()` suggests that you're using Realtime Database.

Realtime Database doesn't have Timestamp type data.  Timestamp is a Firestore concept, and the error message is telling you that you can't write a Timestamp type object to Realtime Database.  If you want to store a moment in time to Realtime Database, you should store a standard unix time in milliseconds represented as a 64 bit integer.

Comment: Or a string, right? By just converting it and then convert it back when you need it?

Comment: I would never store a number as a string.  If you do that, the values are not guaranteed to sort correctly.   I would also never store a timestamp type value as a formatted string.

Comment: Thanks Doug, I was just curious if that was a bad or good practice. :) So you recommend using an int?

Comment: Yeah, that's what my answer says.

Comment: Thanks that's right, I'm using Realtime database for this one. What made me confused was that I use Firestore and it's working fine.